# How do I write test for homebrew formula?

Tags: testing, homebrew

I made an homebrew formula which is now accessible only on my local taps. I want to send pull request to homebrew-core. Now I am required to write test for my formula. How to write that based on example below?

```
test do
  output = shell_output("#{bin}/balance 2>&1", 64)
  assert_match "this is balance #{version}", output
end
```

My formula

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def match
  files = Dir.glob("*")

  if ARGV.length == 0 
  puts "usage: match <keyword>"
  return
 end

files.each { |x| 
if File.directory?(x) 
    puts "#{x}_ found directory"
    puts "***"
next
end

found = false

File.open(x).each_line.with_index do |line, index|
    if line.include? ARGV[0]
       puts "#{x}_ #{index+1}  #{line}" 
       found = true
    end
end

puts "***" if found  
}
end

match
```

Brew formula

```
class Match < Formula
desc "Browse all files inside any directory for a keyword"
homepage "https://github.com/aatalyk/homebrew-match"
url ""
sha256 ""

def install
   bin.install "match"     
end
end
```

Comment: Please share your full formula file.

Comment: @bfontaine I shared it

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the Homebrew formula file, that starts with `class Something < Formula` and defines how to install the software.

Comment: @bfontaine now its there

Answer (score 9):

Tests for shell commands in Homebrew formulae usually usually follow this scenario:

1. create a context usable by the command : a git repository, a directories hierarchy, a sample file, etc.
2. run the command
3. assert the result is correct

In your case since `match` is a `grep -R` -like you could create a bunch of files with some content, then run `match <something>` and ensure it finds the correct files.

You can use any Ruby code in your tests as well as Homebrew utilities such as `shell_output("...command...")` to get the output of a command.

Here is an example of test you could write:

```
class Match < Formula
  # ...

  test do
    # Create two dummy files
    (testpath/"file1").write "foo\nbar\nqux"
    (testpath/"file2").write "bar\nabc"

    # Ensure `match bar` finds both files
    assert_match "file1_ 2  bar\n***\nfile2_ 1  bar",
      shell_output("#{bin}/match bar")

    # Ensure `match abc` finds the second file
    assert_match "file2_ 2  abc", shell_output("#{bin}/match abc")

    # Ensure `match idontmatchanything` doesn’t match any of the files
    assert_not_match(/file[12]/,
      shell_output("#{bin}/match idontmatchanything"))
  end
end
```

`assert_match "something", shell_output("command")` ensures that (1) `command` runs successfully and (2) its output contains "`something`".

Comment: Thanks, @bfontaine I will check it